# [Факт о чем-либо](,) и [какие факты будут дальше]

Tags: пунктуация

Ставится ли запятая в этих предложениях перед «и» и в подобным им предложениях: «Вы можете съесть этот остров(,) и еще 4 факта об островах», «Черная дыра размером в 1 миллиард световых лет(,) и еще несколько фактов о космосе», «Почему у зонта заостренный конец(,) и еще 19 тайн повседневных вещей»? С одной стороны, да, несколько грамматических основ, а с другой стороны, запятая кажется совсем неуместной. Поэтому и вопрос, спасибо заранее

Comment: Здесь первая часть выполняет функцию номинативного предложения. Они здесь объединяются общей идеей подобно тому, как объединяются при пояснении (когда двоеточие). Здесь структура, как когда придаточное вместо однородного члена. Структура: *Этот факт и ещё несколько фактов.* Увы, в правилах такое не рассматривается.

Comment: Типа: *Расскажем вам, почему у зонта заостренный конец и еще 19 тайн повседневных вещей.*

Comment: @oleedd а чем не однородные члены? черная дыра и несколько. почему конец и 19.

Comment: @Буратино Ну да. Мне тоже так кажется. Первая часть в них будто фраза в кавычках (а такое рассматривается просто как член предложения).

Comment: @oleedd да, фразы не выглядят согласованными, больше как номинатив в кавычках, лозунг, рекламный слоган.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы правильно заметили, что приведённые вами предложения являются сложносочинёнными, а вторая часть этих предложений является односоставным назывным предложением. Существуют правила, согласно которым перед союзом ‟и”, соединяющим сложносочинённые, запятая не ставится только в трех случаях: предложения относятся к общему сочетанию, оба предложения односоставные, оба предложения побудительные, или вопросительные, или восклицательные. Ни один из этих случаев не подходит. Кажется вам запятая уместной или нет, но правила есть правила, и запятую ставить нужно.

Во втором предложении оба предложения  действительно односоставные, так что технически есть причина не ставить запятую. А вот первое предложение в третьем предложении технически не является односоставным, так как там опущена связка ‟есть”, как в предложении: ‟На столе яблоко”. Такие предложения не считаются односоставными назывными.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146263/discussion-on-answer-by-jim-korbett---------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 0):

В § 24 (http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120#pp120) Розенталь пишет:

_4. Знаками препинания выделяются не только присоединительные члены предложения, но и присоединительные предложения:

Я шёл в каком-то опьянении, да и было от чего (Гарш.);

Прекрасная песенка, да и Юлия Владимировна прекрасно изволят петь (Пис);

Цветы всё дорогие, и где он их взял? (Остр.)_

В предложениях

«Вы можете съесть этот остров, и еще 4 факта об островах»,

«Почему у зонта заостренный конец, и еще 19 тайн повседневных вещей» автора вопроса вторая часть --

это присоединительное двусоставное предложение, так как есть нарече *еще* в роли обстоятельства, которое относится к опущенному сказуемому.

В предложениях, приведенных автором вопроса, И -- присоединительный союз.

Без *еще* это были бы назывные предложения собственно бытийного типа:

«Вы можете съесть этот остров, и 4 факта об островах»,

«Почему у зонта заостренный конец, и 19 тайн повседневных вещей».

Вторая часть этих предложений была присоединительным членом, а не предложением, но запятая всё равно была бы нужна.

В предложении

«Черная дыра размером в 1 миллиард световых лет, и еще несколько фактов о космосе»

первая часть -- назывное предложение предметно-бытийного типа, вторая часть -- неполное предложение, двусоставное, с пропущенным сказуемым, так как в ней есть обстоятельство *еще*.

«Черная дыра размером в 1 миллиард световых лет, и еще несколько фактов о космосе» -- части этого предложения не односоставные, поэтому запятая нужна.

Вывод: во всех трех предложениях автора вопроса запятые нужны.

В предложении

«Черная дыра размером в 1 миллиард световых лет, и еще несколько фактов о космосе»

-- здесть пропущено сказуемое *есть*, а *еще* наречие, которое к нему относится и выполняет роль обстоятельства.

Если же предположить, что *еще* -- частица, которая относится к пропущенному сказуемому *есть*, то  запятая нужна.

Еще есть два варианта, как рассматривать слово *несколько*: как наречие или как местоимение. В зависимости от  этого *еще* может быть наречием или
числительным. И соответственно разные варианты осмысления предложения и постановки запятой.

Здесь нужен контекст.

*Там не пропущено "есть", вот похожий пример: Дартаньян и ещё три мушкетёра. Никто не хочет сказать, что есть ещё три. Так и там: никто не хочет сказать, что ещё есть несколько фактов. Это названия видео. Хотят сказать, о чём будет видео. Смысл не в том, что у них есть ещё факты*.

Спасибо большое, oleedd!
Теперь понятно.

Comment: Но там "и ещё" не присоединительное. Например: *Расскажу это и ещё два факта.* Поставите запятую?

Comment: Какое сказуемое пропущено? Глагол "есть" там не подразумевается, там не смысл в том, что есть ещё факты. *Этот факт и ещё несколько фактов.* Где вы здесь видите пропущенное сказуемое?

Comment: Вот пример из справочника Розенталя с "и ещё": *Из-под сена виднелись: самовар, кадка с мороженной формой и ещё кой-какие' привлекательные узелки и коробочки* (Л. Толстой). Вот пример из другого справочника: *Азарт этот ещё увеличился, когда отец вытащил огромного окуня и ещё огромнейшего линя, а у Евсеича сорвалась какая-то большая рыба и вдобавок щука оторвала удочку* (С. Аксаков).

Comment: Там не пропущено "есть", вот похожий пример: *Дартаньян и ещё три мушкетёра.* Никто не хочет сказать, что есть ещё три. Так и там: никто не хочет сказать, что ещё есть несколько фактов. Это названия видео. Хотят сказать, о чём будет видео. Смысл не в том, что у них есть ещё факты. Такой смысл никто не закладывает, кроме вас.